# How do you remove a middle initial from a name in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out something that seems like it should be simple. I'm trying to remove the middle initial from names, but I'm not sure how to do it without making a replace() for every letter of the alphabet. This is what I'm looking for:

(Starts as)

"John D Smith"

"Robert B Johnson"

(Ends as)

"John Smith"

"Robert Johnson"

What is the simplest way of accomplishing the above in Python? The middle initial is random, but is always surrounded by white space.

Comment: re.sub(' [A-Z]* ', ' ', "John D Smith")???

Comment: Is every input name guaranteed to have a middle initial? Or will there be some names that are just "firstname lastname", which you want to remain unchanged?

Comment: Remember that names in practice are actually tricky.  What do you do with something like "George R R Martin"?  [This article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) has some interesting thoughts about the parsing of names.

Comment: BAE, the re thing is what I needed. I didn't even realize Python had a regular expression module. You rock. And, whoever is giving thumbs down is a troll, I couldn't find a similar question anywhere on the site.

Comment: @Matthew I am also curious why my answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May this help, based on your post

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(' [A-Z]* ', ' ', "John D Smith")
'John Smith'
>>> re.sub(' [A-Z]* ', ' ', "Robert B Johnson")
'Robert Johnson'
```

Comment: Curious why downvoted. Based on posted info, my answer works well. If more info posted, I will give more detailed and generic answer.

Comment: I gave a thumbs up, it worked perfectly. I'm also giving you the correct answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = "Name N Name".split() # Splits string at whitespace into list
del name[1] # Deletes 2nd item (middle initial)
removed_middle_initial = " ".join(name) # "Name Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Built-in string manipulation makes this pretty easy.

```
[name.split()[0] + " " + name.split()[2] for name in names]
```

This is assuming that first and last names will not include any white space characters. If more advanced requirements are need then you would obviously need to handle those conditions.

Comment: Or without calling `split` multiple times: `' '.join(c for i,c in enumerate(names.split()) if i != 1)`  Posted as  a comment because really it's doing the same thing, just differently...

Comment: Indeed. I was trying to think of how to do this without splitting twice and that was clearly the way to do it. Thanks @larsks

Answer (score 0):

`(?=)` for look ahead. `[A-Z]` for 1 letter initial.

```
import re
re.sub(' [A-Z](?= )', '', "John D Smith")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) method to replace the middle initial with a space.

```
>>> re.sub("\s[A-Za-z]\s", " ", "John D Smith")
John Smith
```

This is using the `\s` alphabetic character class to look for the first single letter that is surrounded by whitespace. It then replaces that entire 3 character string (space, letter, space) with a single space.